# path between two disjoint sets (path algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have the following problem. I have two disjoint set of vertices in a graph and I want to find out whether there exists a path between those two sets.

I only need to know that such a path exists.

I have read somewhere that this can be solved using the union-find data structure but I couldn`t find an algorithm that suits my needs

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354330/how-to-determine-if-two-nodes-are-connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be efficiently solved using a [Union-Find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Denote by `A` and `B` the two sets of vertices and initialize a Union-Find data structure such that each vertex `v` of the graph belongs to its own set.

Let `a1` be an arbitrary vertex of `A`. Perform `UNION(FIND(a1), FIND(a))` for each vertex `a` in `A` (all but `a1` which is going to be the representative of the set). Then do the same for the vertices in `B`: Let `b1` be an arbitrary vertex of `B` and perform `UNION(FIND(b1), FIND(b))` for each vertex `b` of `B`.

Now `FIND(a1)` returns exactly the set of vertices belonging to `A` and `FIND(b1)` returns exactly the set vertices belonging to `B`. In particular, if `A` and `B` intersect with each other then `FIND(a1)=FIND(b1)`. For each edge `(u,v)` in the graph, perform a `UNION(FIND(u), FIND(v))`.

There exists a path between `A` and `B` if and only if during the above process you have merged the set of `a1` with the set of `b1`.

The number of UNION/FIND operations you've done is at most `O(|E|+|A|+|B|)`. Hence, the running time of the algorithm is `O(alpha(n)*(|E|+|A|+|B|))` where `alpha(n)` is the [Inverse Ackerman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse). The Inverse Ackerman function, which grows very slowly, is an upper bound on the running time of each UNION or FIND operation.