# How to determine if two nodes are part of a same tree/graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I was asked this question in an interview to determine if two people are directly or indirectly connected on facebook.

say a has a few friends b,c,d,e and c had few friends b,d,f,g and f has friends x,y,z. then a and z are indirect friends.

Is there a good algorithm to found out how they are connected?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354330/how-to-determine-if-two-nodes-are-connected) post had similar question but he has too many criterias so i thought there must be a better way to do it. Can anyone just advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to get the minimum hops to reach that particular friend if reachable. With some book keeping on the nodes visited so far you'll be able to get the friends traversed to reach the friend being searched.

This algorithm runs in Liner time `O(V + E)`.

**PsuedoCode:**

Breadth-First-Search(Graph, Root, Goal):

> ```
> create empty set Checked
> create empty queue Queue      
>
> add Root to Checked
> Queue.enqueue(Root)                      
>
> while Queue is not empty {
>     Current = Queue.dequeue()
>     if Current.has(Goal) {
>         return Current
>     }
>     for each Node that is adjacent to Current {
>         if Node is not in Checked {
>             Checked.add(Node)
>             Queue.enqueue(Node)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

If the friends that needs to visited before finding the friend being searched is greater than 1 you can say they are indirectly connected.

This can also be used to check if they are connected or not.