# Check if there is a path that connects 2 vertices in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I'm trying to write a code for checking a path exists from vertex `v1` to `v2` in a given graph. 
It **works for certain test cases and gives runtime error (time limit exceeded) for others**.

```
bool HasPath(int V, int** edges, int* visited, int v1, int v2)
{
    if (edges[v1][v2] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] == 1)
            continue;

        if (edges[v1][i] == 1)
        {
            bool sa = HasPath(V, edges, visited, i, v2);
            visited[i] = 1;
            if (sa == false)
                continue;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int V, E;
    cin >> V >> E;

    int** edges = new int*[V];
    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
    {
        edges[i] = new int[V];
        for (int j = 0; j<V; j++)
        {
            edges[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<E; i++)
    {
        int f, s;
        cin >> f >> s;
        edges[f][s] = 1;
        edges[s][f] = 1;
    }

    int* visited = new int[V];
    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
        visited[i] = 0;

    int v1, v2;
    cin >> v1 >> v2;
    bool ans = HasPath(V, edges, visited, v1, v2);
    if (ans == 1)
        cout << "true";
    else
        cout << "false";
    return 0;
}
```

Edges is the adjacency matrix. And the graph is bidirectional. The aim is to find if path exists from `v1` to `v2`.
Input Format:
Line 1: `V` and `E` 
Next `E` lines : Two integers `a` and `b`, denoting that there exists an edge between vertex `a` and vertex `b` (separated by space)
Line `(E+2)` : Two integers `v1` and `v2` (separated by space)

Sample Test case that fails:

```
6 3
5 3
0 1
3 4
0 3 (these are the vertices between which we need to find path)
```

The graph for the above test case:

[image: Here is the image of the graph for the above test case]

Sample Test case that passes:

```
4 4
0 1
0 3
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

Comment: Please post some sample input where the program fails. Hard to help otherwise.

Comment: What kind of runtime errors are you encountering? Segmentation fault is common when dealing with pointer data types, make sure you take care of array index overflow or other things that may cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: For a simple solution, see David Norman's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354330/how-to-determine-if-two-nodes-are-connected

Comment: Also, have a common indexing convention across the code. If you're using 0 based index, make sure your input is processed like that.

Comment: Your code is timing out because the time complexity is too high.

Comment: What is `V`? Can you make a simple graph to illustrate one of your sample cases?

Comment: @SaCh Is it working fine for 4 vertices but not for 6 vertices. What suggestions would you suggest to change this code?

Comment: @L_J V is the number of vertices in the graph. E is the number of edges in the graph. I'll try to add asap.

Comment: Look where you set visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change I made is that in the recursive function `HasPath` mark as visited (`visited[i] = 1;`) before the recursive call. I also made some minor changes in your codes.

Also, don't forget to delete dynamically allocated memory (even if it's not important here.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool HasPath(int V, int** edges, int* visited, int v1, int v2)
{
    if (edges[v1][v2] == 1)
        return true;

    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i] != 1 && edges[v1][i] == 1)
        {
            visited[i] = 1;
            if (HasPath(V, edges, visited, i, v2))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() 
{
    int V, E;
    cin >> V >> E;

    int** edges = new int*[V];
    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
    {
        edges[i] = new int[V];
        for (int j = 0; j<V; j++)
        {
            edges[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<E; i++)
    {
        int f, s;
        cin >> f >> s;
        edges[f][s] = 1;
        edges[s][f] = 1;
    }

    int* visited = new int[V];
    for (int i = 0; i<V; i++)
        visited[i] = 0;

    int v1, v2;
    cin >> v1 >> v2;
    bool ans = HasPath(V, edges, visited, v1, v2);
    cout << (ans == 1 ? "true" : "false");

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        delete[] edges[i];

    delete[] edges;
    delete[] visited;

    return 0;
}
```