# Compute reachability of elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, reachability

I have a list of tuples like this.

```
a = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(6,5),(7,8)]
```

In this list 1 relates to 2 and then 2 relates to 5 and 5 relates to 6 therefore 1 relates to 6. Similarly I need to find the relations between other elements in tuples. I need a function that takes the input values and outputs as follows:

```
input = (1,6) #output = True
input = (5,3) #output = True
input = (2,8) #output = False
```

I do not have knowledge of itertools or map functions. Can they be used to solve these types of problems? 
And for the sake of curiosity and interest where can I find these types of questions to solve and where are these types of problems encountered in real life situations?

Comment: Added the tag! Ok. Thanks. I will search online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354330/how-to-determine-if-two-nodes-are-connected .

Comment: Your tuples define connectivity. In this example, (1,2,3,4,5,6) are connected and (7,8) are. You can just merge tuples into sets, iteratively.

Comment: @BoarGules: no this is much simpler than the Traveling Salesman Problem and this is not NP-complete. There is no concept of 'distance' or 'shortest distance'. Nodes are either connected or not. (1,2) are connected and so are (1,3) and (1,4). We represent this simply by merging those tuples into the set {1,2,3,4} like I said above. And so on, iteratively. Just make sure to handle the case where two sets merge i.e. a tuple (x,y) when x is in set X and y is in set Y.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you have some code that you've tried to use, but there's a specific problem?

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php could help

Comment: Your answer is the solution to my problem. Thank you! @smci

Comment: I formulated the problem on my own to practice python. I wanted to represent relations. So I created a list of tuples. Then I thought of how I can find the relations by writing code. It was for my own practice @mkrieger

Comment: This problem is typically called disjoint-set problem (or union-find), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure. You don't need graph theory to solve this problem. I think `graph-theory` label is unnecessary.

Comment: It didn't help that the [tag wiki for \[reachability\] referred to the iOS app not the concept, so I posted on Meta to get that fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372993/definition-of-reachability).

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily done by considering the tuples as edges in a graph. The question is then reduced to checking if there is a path between the two nodes.

There exists lots of nice libraries for this, see e.g. [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html)

```
import networkx as nx

a = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(6,5),(7,8)]

G = nx.Graph(a)

nx.has_path(G, 1, 6)  # True
nx.has_path(G, 5, 3)  # True
nx.has_path(G, 2, 8)  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981943/4223053) nicely states your problem as a graph problem, where every time you need to run your algorithm you need to check for the existence of a path between your input vertices. The time complexity for every query then depends on the size, order, diameter, degree of the underlying graph.

However, if you intend to run this algorithm many times with the same array `a`, it may be worth doing some preprocessing on the input graph to find the connected components ([Wikipedia : connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))) first. In that case you can get *constant time* for every query. Here is the code I suggest :

```
# NOTE : tested using python 3.6.1
# WARNING : no input sanitization

a = [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(6,5),(7,8)]
n = 8 # order of the underlying graph

# prepare graph as lists of neighbors for every vertex, i.e. adjacency lists (extra unused vertex '0', just to match the value range of the problem)
graph = [[] for i in range(n+1)]
for edge in a:
  graph[edge[0]].append(edge[1])
  graph[edge[1]].append(edge[0])
print( "graph : " + str(graph) )

# list of unprocessed vertices : contains all of them at the beginning
unprocessed_vertices = {i for i in range(1,n+1)}

# subroutine to discover the connected component of a vertex
def build_component():
  component = [] # current connected component
  curr_vertices = {unprocessed_vertices.pop()} # locally unprocessed vertices, initialize with one of the globally unprocessed vertices
  while len(curr_vertices) > 0:
    curr_vertex = curr_vertices.pop() # vertex to be processed
    # add unprocessed neighbours of current vertex to the set of vertices to process
    for neighbour in graph[curr_vertex]:
      if neighbour in unprocessed_vertices:
        curr_vertices.add(neighbour)
        unprocessed_vertices.remove(neighbour)
    component.append(curr_vertex)
  return component

# main algorithm : graph traversal on multiple connected components
components = []
while len(unprocessed_vertices) > 0:
  components.append( build_component() )
print( "components : " + str(components) )

# assign a number to each component
component_numbers = [None] * (n+1)
curr_number = 1
for comp in components:
  for vertex in comp:
    component_numbers[vertex] = curr_number
  curr_number += 1
print( "component_numbers : " + str(component_numbers) )

# main functionality
def is_connected( pair ):
  return component_numbers[pair[0]] == component_numbers[pair[1]]

# run main functionnality on inputs : every call is executed in constant time now, regardless of the size of the graph
print( is_connected( (1,6) ) )
print( is_connected( (5,3) ) )
print( is_connected( (2,8) ) )
```

I don't really know about the most likely situations where this problem could be encountered, but I suppose it can have application is some clustering tasks, or maybe if you want to know if it is possible to go from one place to another. If the edges of the graph represent dependencies between modules, this problem would tell you if two parts depend on each other, so maybe some potential applications in compiling or the managment of large projects. The underlying problem is a "Connected component" problem which is among the problems we know polynomial algorithms for.

It is generally very useful to model these kind of problems with graphs as these objects have a very simple structure, and most of the time we can reduce the original problem to a well known problem on graphs.